# Create a dictionary from key value, where the keys and values are pair types

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dictionary object

```
{('ABE2', '170xi iii plus'): (1, '1178.55', 1178.55),
 ('ABE2', '170xi4+'): (1, '2844.12', 2844.12),
 ('ABE2', '1900gsr-1'): (30, '115.0', 3450.0)}
```

and I have a empty dataframe that looks like this

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['location_sitecode', 'model_name', 'total_quantity', 'cost_per_device', 'total_cost'])
```

I want to append each entry into the rows of df_test. I tried this

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data = result_dict, columns=['location_sitecode', 'model_name', 'total_quantity', 'cost_per_device', 'total_cost'])
```

But I just get the columns and not the data I want inserted into the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack dictionary entries as shown below:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([[*k, *v] for k,v in d.items()], columns=df_test.columns)
print(df_test)
```

---

```
  location_sitecode      model_name  total_quantity cost_per_device  total_cost
0              ABE2  170xi iii plus               1         1178.55     1178.55
1              ABE2         170xi4+               1         2844.12     2844.12
2              ABE2       1900gsr-1              30           115.0     3450.00
```

Comment: I love this! Looks similar to C++ syntax to me.

Answer (score 2):

Given your format, you could use the index and reset it:

```
df_test = (pd.DataFrame(result_dict.values(),
                        columns=['total_quantity', 'cost_per_device', 'total_cost'],
                        index=result_dict.keys()
                       )
             .rename_axis(['location_sitecode', 'model_name'])
             .reset_index()
           )
```

Or, with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

df_test = pd.DataFrame(map(chain.from_iterable, result_dict.items()),
                       columns=['location_sitecode', 'model_name', 'total_quantity',
                                'cost_per_device', 'total_cost']
                       )
```

Output:

```
  location_sitecode      model_name  total_quantity cost_per_device  total_cost
0              ABE2  170xi iii plus               1         1178.55     1178.55
1              ABE2         170xi4+               1         2844.12     2844.12
2              ABE2       1900gsr-1              30           115.0     3450.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(d).T\
           .rename_axis(['location_sitecode', 'model_name'])\
           .set_axis(['total_quantity', 'cost_per_device', 'total_cost'], axis=1)\
           .reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  location_sitecode      model_name total_quantity cost_per_device total_cost
0              ABE2  170xi iii plus              1         1178.55    1178.55
1              ABE2         170xi4+              1         2844.12    2844.12
2              ABE2       1900gsr-1             30           115.0     3450.0
```

Comment: I recomment to replace `pd.DataFrame(result_dict).T` by `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict, orient='index')`, this avoids messing up the dtypes through the transposition ;)